# What would be the downsides/blockers for hosting a single page app on Amazon S3?

Tags: architecture, amazon-s3, cross-domain, blogs

Basically I want to make a blog. Since the actual blog content is static, it seems fitting to upload it to S3 - cheap & basically infinitely scalable in case Hacker News or Reddit ever hit it (unlikely, but you never know).
However, I want to have some dynamic parts to it, like search.

My current thinking is that the blog would be a HTML uploaded to a domain on S3 while the actual server side component that would be called from Javascript and would return the search results would be hosted somewhere else (probably in a subdomain).

Basically the first hit is always to S3. If the user wants to get more "interactive" only then does he actually query a server. But as long as the access is read only, no extra interaction (most likely scenario in case of a traffic spike), S3 can handle things gracefully, unlike a puny VPS.

According to this question/answer: [Serving Django API on Heroku and single-page app on Amazon S3 on the same domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15641124/serving-django-api-on-heroku-and-single-page-app-on-amazon-s3-on-the-same-domain) it is not possible.

Is this still the case now? Thank you.

Comment: Were you hoping to use an existing package or write your own? Since you're willing to use a subdomain, this is very do-able if you use the proper CORS headers, but I am not aware of any packages which can do this for you

Comment: I can write my own. So I can host the entry point on S3, a back end on a subdomain and I just need to use proper CORS headers. I need to do some research about CORS then, since I barely know what it is, but I don't know how to implement it. Do you have any recommended reading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend that you configure `www.yoursite.com` to point to your S3 bucket and run the dynamic content on a subdomain (`dynamic.yoursite.com`). I don;t know how you plan to do the dynamic portion, but you have several options:

1. Keep them as separate sites which link to each other. This may work well, for example, if you have your pages on S3 and your search index on your VPS. When the user does a search, the search request is POSTed to a page on `dynamic.yoursite.com`, which returns the results list. This results list can reference CSS, scripts, and images from `www.yoursite.com` as needed, and each result can link back to the static content.
2. For more complex sharing, both S3 or your VPS can be configured to allow CORS. This will allow AJAX requests to be sent as well. (Note that while [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=cors) is very wide, there are still a few that do not support CORS yet)

   - On the VPS, your code would need to [return an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) allowing the origin `www.yoursite.com`. This allows static pages to access dynamic content.
   - S3 could also be [configured to allow the origin `dynamic.yoursite.com`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html) if required. This allows dynamic pages to access static content.

Comment: It is possible to set the root domain on S3? I.e. mysite.com instead of www.mysite.com?
This is for a completely new site.

Comment: Yes. Simply follow Amazon's documentation. I recommended the `www` only from the fact that this is fairly standard.